# Ionic Base64ToGallery - Error while saving image - Android

Tags: android, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

I'm creating a chat app at the moment, similar to for example whats app and now I got problems with saving the Images on android with the error message: "Error while saving image". On iOS all works without any problems.
I'm getting the Image from the Server as a base64 string.
I thought it maybe has to do something with the permissions but I checked them with @ionic-native/androidPermissions and this @ionic-nativ/diagnostics and both plugins told me that I got the required permissions.

The Code of the Saving Image function:

```
 savePhoto(base64String){
 this.base64ToGallery.base64ToGallery(base64String, {prefix: '_img', mediaScanner: true}).then(
    res => {
        console.log("Saved image to gallery:", res)
       //more code on this point, but shouldn't affect the base64 plugin
     },
    err => console.log('Error saving image to gallery:', err)
    )
```

Code of grantPermission with androidPermissions:

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
      result => console.log("Has Permission?", result.hasPermission),
      err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    )
```

Code with ionic diagnostics:

```
getStatusPermissionDiagnostics(){
    let successCallback = (isAvailable) => { console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable); }
    let errorCallback = (e) => console.error(e);
    this.diagnostic.getExternalStorageAuthorizationStatus().then(
      successCallback).catch(errorCallback)
  }

grantPermissionDiagnostics(){
    let successCallback = (isAvailable) => { console.log('Is available? ' + isAvailable); }
    let errorCallback = (e) => console.error(e);
    this.diagnostic.requestRuntimePermission(this.diagnostic.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(successCallback).catch(errorCallback)
  }
```

UPDATE:
I now found out that this happens with Android 11 and 10, With Android Version 9 I got no problems at all.

Comment: Try to add in manifest.xml

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Thanks I will try that, can you tell me how I can add that to the config.xml in ionic?

Comment: No you can add "platforms\android\app\src\main ->AndroidManifest.xml"

Comment: I tried it in a different way, I directly changed it in the apk but now my app keeps crashing on startup

Comment: open android studio and attach android device and check logs in log tab